# How to setup server-side full response caching in Apollo Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, graphql, apollo-server

I am trying to setup a cache according to [this guide](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/caching/) for one expensive query that has a result that changes only once a day. The query takes 7-8 seconds and most it is after the DB query, because the response returned from the resolver must be heavily processed.

I am using `apollo-server-express` library and the change pluging is `apollo-server-plugin-response-cache`.

This is what I have done:

```
server.js

const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express')
const responseCachePlugin = require('apollo-server-plugin-response-cache')

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: async ({ req }) => {
    // ...
  },
  plugins: [responseCachePlugin()]
```

```
resolvers.js

personDetails: async (root, args, ctx, info) => {
      info.cacheControl.setCacheHint({ maxAge: 600 })
      const persons = await Person.find({}).populate('details')

      // processing the data

      return processedData
}
```

I expect the resolver to run once and then after that the response should be returned from the cache almost instantly. This doesn't work. I am doing something wrong or I haven't understood how this should work.

I tried to put cache hints also in the schema, but didn't get any better results.

Answer (score 3):

It should work. Here is a working example:

`server.ts`:

```js
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server-express';
import express from 'express';
import responseCachePlugin from 'apollo-server-plugin-response-cache';

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    personDetails: String
  }
`;
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    personDetails: async (root, args, ctx, info) => {
      console.log(`[${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}] Query.personDetails`);
      info.cacheControl.setCacheHint({ maxAge: 10 });
      return 'This is person details';
    },
  },
};

const app = express();
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  plugins: [responseCachePlugin()],
});

apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app });

const server = app.listen({ port: 4000 }, () => {
  console.log(`The server is running in http://localhost:4000${apolloServer.graphqlPath}`);
});
```

The request logs:

```sh
The server is running in http://localhost:4000/graphql
[1:51:27 PM] Query.personDetails
[1:51:52 PM] Query.personDetails
```

The response header:

```
cache-control: max-age=10, public
```

The first graphql request send at `[1:51:27 PM]`. In the next 10 seconds, all requests sent will hit the cache(defaults to an in-memory LRU cache), which means the graphql resolver `personDetails` will not execute. The graphql response will be read from the cache and sent to client-side.

After 10 seconds, I send another graphql request at `[1:51:52 PM]`. The cache is expired. So this request will not hit the in-memory cache. The graphql resolver will execute and generate a new value.

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57243105

Comment: Sorry for reviving this question after over a year of silence. I'm currently in the same situation, and this snippet boils down exactly to what I'm doing in my code.
The problem I'm facing is that the result of the resolver never gets put in the cache, hence the resolver is still executed on each request. Do you know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is an old question but it might help someone solve server side caching issue in Apollo.

So as per my understanding the `apollo-server-plugin-response-cache` plugin only works if the response from the underlying REST API have control-cache header. In case there is no cache-control header in your REST API it can be overriden in restDataSouce GET calls as below.

```html
return this.get(`uri_path`,"", {cacheOptions: { ttl: 1}});
```

After that continue using info.cacheControl at the resolvers as suggested in the example from the question snippets. maxAge there will override the time mentioned in the cacheOptions.